# I just can't activate the conduit on Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Hey Guys I read a lot of posts online on how to activate the conduit. I tried to surround it with prismarine blocks underwater. Maybe the prismarine blocks have some kind of pattern or formation. If there are any I hope you can help me. Thanks for taking your time to read my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a certain formation that the primsarine, dark prismarine, prismarine bricks or sea lanterns need to be in to activate the conduit.
[image: Layer 1]
[image: Layer 2]
[image: Layer 3]
[image: Layer 4]
[image: Layer 5]
Empty spaces can be anything.

These images are screenshots I took from the [conduit page on Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Conduit).

The following is also from the conduit page:

> When activated, conduits give the "Conduit Power" effect to all players in contact with water or rain, within a spherical range of 32-96 blocks. This effect stops the breath meter from decreasing, gives underwater night vision and increases mining speed. Conduits can be activated in any biome and at any height or depth.
>
> To activate, a conduit needs to be surrounded on all sides by water (source blocks, flowing water, and/or waterlogged blocks) and the conduit and water must be enclosed in an activation frame. The frame is built up of blocks in three 5×5 open squares centered on the conduit, one around each axis. Only prismarine, dark prismarine, prismarine bricks and sea lantern blocks in the frame contribute to activation. A minimum of 16 blocks are required, and produce an effect range of 32 blocks. Prismarine-type slabs (including double slabs) and stairs cannot be used to activate the conduit.
>
> The effect range of the conduit is 16 blocks for every seven blocks in the frame, though the effect does not activate until the minimum of 16 blocks are included in the build. Thus, it extends to 48 at 21 blocks, 64 at 28 blocks, 80 at 35 blocks, and 96 with a complete frame of 42 blocks. A complete frame also carries the additional advantage of attacking hostile mobs within 8 blocks of the conduit by 4 every 2 seconds, if they are in contact with water or rain.
>
> Other blocks used as part of the frame (including prismarine stairs, slabs, and double slabs) have no effect on activation, and can be omitted. Any blocks outside the frame but within the 5×5×5 cube that encompasses it likewise have no effect.

Comment: @SofoniasAyele You’re welcome. If this solution worked for you, please accept it. See [this page on the help centre](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). You also get 2 reputation points!

Comment: Sorry cherry. I was so hung up on Minecraft that I forgot to accept it. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure there is a ring around the conduit and it must be under water. There has to be one block space between the conduit and the prismarine. Make sure it has it’s own space, which means breaking seagrass around it.

Answer (score 0):

I am testing this in bedrock and the range for the conduit at maximum is not 96.  I've done a frame of prismarine, dark prismarine, and prismarine bricks.  I had the full frame and 96 blocks away from the conduit did not work.  I even added blocks until it was a full cube.  The range is 72 blocks from the conduit, outside of 72 and the effect starts to countdown.